# Different layout of row in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I'm working with the firebase recyclerview, I would like to create different layouts for the first three items. My problem is that I can get 3 different layouts, but when I go to scrolling, litter items take the same layout as the first ones and this does not have to happen.

I've seen it need to be implemented getItemViewType, but with my code I can not.
I'm definitely doing something in my code, what to fix?

```
public class RankingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


TextView name_txt, txt_number;
TextView point_txt;
CardView card;
LinearLayout layout;
ImageView primi_img;
CircleImageView profile_img;
ProgressBar progressBar;

String position_;

public RankingViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    name_txt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ranking_name);
    point_txt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ranking_point);
   txt_number = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ranking_txt_number);
    card = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ranking_card);
    layout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ranking_layout);
    primi_img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ranking_img);
    profile_img = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ranking_profile_img);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ranking_progress_img);

}

public void bindToPost(RankingItem rankingItem, final int position, int count) {

    point_txt.setText(String.valueOf(rankingItem.point));

    position_ = String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition());
    txt_number.setText(position_);

    if (position_.equals("1")){
       ....
    }
    if (position_.equals("2")){

       .....
    }
    if (position_.equals("3")){

       ....
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you include a picture of your recycler view referring to your problem inside the posts?